# Mysql encryption type

Tags: mysql, wordpress, encryption, phpmyadmin, passwords

I'm trying to change the wordpress admin password(I lost the password and can't access the email), but currently I could access the phpmyadmin, I want to change the admin password through db, but I don't know which kind of encryption the back-end used.Could anyone help me figure it out? Or is there any other way to change the admin password through db?
I can't post images, the password likes "$P$BOZMgyp.M.2Zy1zj3R7WFrJfc/nQPG1" or "$P$BPsJKQdT99XsX/C5PfHg4w4QMEVvS40" after encryption. It looks like it always start with "$P$B" sth.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it uses [blowfish or extended DES](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's Md5.
Did You try changing the password from the db with MD5?

This should work.